# JUnit tests getter called before setter

Tags: java, junit

In `JUnit` is there a place where I can define how methods to be tested should flow?

I have class called `Location` which I have written a test for. All tests pass apart from `testGetName` which is called before `testSetName`.

It makes the tests fail. How can I fix this?

```
public class LocationTest {

    Location instance;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        instance = new Location();
    }              

    @Test
    public void testGetLongitude() {
        System.out.println("getLongitude");
        double expResult = 0.0;
        double result = instance.getLongitude();
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
    }    

    @Test
    public void testSetLongitude() {
        System.out.println("setLongitude");
        double longitude = 0.0;
        instance.setLongitude(longitude);
    }    

    @Test
    public void testSetName() {
        System.out.println("setName");
        String name = "";
        instance.setName(name);
    }

    /**
     * Test of getName method, of class Location.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetName() {
        System.out.println("getName");
               String expResult = "Mock Location";
        String result = instance.getName();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh dear, don't do this.  Test the required behaviour of your class.  Don't write a test for each individual method.  And frankly, writing tests for getters and setters is really not a good use of your time.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, I agree 100% with that last point especially when we have things like [`auto-value`](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md) designed specifically to eliminate the need to write all the redundancies of value classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No there isn't.

Long answer: Pretty sure there is a question already asked here on SO about this topic.

In general, tests should not maintain state from test to test, so if you have a getter test that depends on a setter test, chances are that you are doing the test wrong.

If you want to test getters and setters, do it all in one test; i.e. **Test the setter by using the getter** and if both operations are successful, then the getter and setter work!

---

To answer your question, there is one help JUnit has to offer with respect to this and it is found here:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-execution-order

In short, the options you have to ordering your tests are to either rely on the **order the JVM specifies**, or **lexicographic ordering of the method names**. These will not solve your problem because you seem to want a very specific order; i.e. `set` -> `get`